# Fields not GROUP BY creating multiple records instead of a single record

Tags: sql

I am stuck and have been looking at this for too long. I have the below query that i want to return a single record showing sales price, cost price and subsequent charges but when I add in my case when statement these create multiple records.  Looking for any assistance.

Current Output
[image: Current Output]

Expected Output
[image: Expected Output]

Current Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CONCAT(OBCUNO,'',OKCUNM) CUSTOMER,
OBORNO CO_NUMBER,
OBPONR CO_LINE,
OBPROJ PROJECT,
OBITNO ITEM,
OBHDPR M3_STYLE,
MMITDS CUST_STYLE,
MMFUDS DESCRIPTION,
OBORQA ORDER_QTY,
M9UCOS FACILITY_COST,
OBUCOS DISTRO_COST,

CASE WHEN OBUCOS = M9UCOS THEN 'MATCH' ELSE 'NO MATCH' END AS COST_PRC_MATCH,

OBSAPR SALE_PRC,

CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'PNP' THEN O7CRFA * OBORQA ELSE 0 END AS 'PNP CHG', 

CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'DTY' THEN O7CRAM * OBORQA ELSE 0 END AS 'DUTY CHG', 

OBVTCD VAT_CD,
SUM(CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'PNP' THEN OBSAPR * OBORQA + (CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'PNP' THEN OBORQA * O7CRFA ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_LN_AMT
FROM MVXJDTA.OOLINE
    LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.OOLICH 
        ON O7CONO = OBCONO
        AND O7ORNO = OBORNO
        AND O7PONR = OBPONR
    LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.OCUSMA 
        ON OKCONO = OBCONO
        AND OKCUNO = OBCUNO
    LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.MITMAS
        ON MMCONO = OBCONO
        AND MMITNO = OBITNO
    LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.MITFAC
        ON M9CONO = OBCONO
        AND M9FACI = OBFACI
        AND M9ITNO = OBITNO
    LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.CVATPC
        ON CVCONO = OBCONO
        AND CVDIVI = OBDIVI
        AND CVVTCD = OBVTCD
WHERE OBCONO = '610'
        AND OBORNO = '2000000190'
                
GROUP BY OBCUNO,OKCUNM,OBORNO,OBCUOR,OBPROJ,OBITNO,OBHDPR,MMITDS,MMFUDS,OBSAPR,M9UCOS,OBUCOS,OBVTCD,OBORQA,CVVTP1,O7CRFA,O7CRAM, O7CRID,OBPONR
```

Comment: Try adding the column `O7CRID` to the query so there is visibility of that.  Also, why are `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` both being used in the query?  Typically, `GROUP BY` is sufficient when using `SUM` in a query.

Comment: Also, `TOTAL_LN_AMT` can be simplified `SUM(IIF(O7CRID = 'PNP', OBORQA * (OBSAPR + O7CRFA), 0) AS TOTAL_LN_AMT`

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE statements are generating multiple values so you will get multiple rows in your result. E.g. pnp_chg has values of 0 and 168.4

Possibly you need to put SUM round each CASE statement - assuming that’s how you want to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and reviewing the output, using PIVOT function worked to provide a better result.

```
select * 
from 
(
  select 
  O7ORNO,
  O7CRID,
  O7CRAM

  from MVXJDTA.OOLICH 
) src
pivot
(
  sum(O7CRAM)
  for O7CRID in ([PNP], [DTY], [HAN])
) piv
 order by O7ORNO;
```

The issue I have now is the ISNULL and where to place it to remove the NULL values.

| O7ORNO | PNP | DTY | HAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000329 | 0.85 | NULL | NULL |

I have tried to add the ISNULL into the sub query against O7CRAM but that did not remove the NULL values